# MongoDB Group querying for Embeded Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document which has structure like

```
{
"_id" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID+2014-11-26",
"_class" : "weight",
"items" : [
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:08:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 98.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:18:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 95.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:28:38.663Z"),
        "value" : 90.5
    }
],
"source" : "MANUAL",
"to" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:08:38.716Z"),
"from" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:08:38.716Z"),
"userId" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID",
"createdDate" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:38:38.776Z")
}
{
"_id" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID+2014-11-25",
"_class" : "weight",
"items" : [
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:08:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 198.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:18:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 195.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:28:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 190.5
    }
],
"source" : "MANUAL",
"to" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:08:38.716Z"),
"from" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:08:38.716Z"),
"userId" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID",
"createdDate" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:38:38.893Z")
}
```

The query that want to fire on this document structure,

1. finding documents for a particular user id
2. unwinding the embedded array
3. Grouping the documents based over _id with -

   4. summing the items.value of the embedded array
   5. getting the minimum of the items.dateTime of the embedded array

**Note**. The sum and min, I want to get as a object i.e. { value : sum , dateTime : min of the items.dateTime} inside an array of items

Can this be achieved in an single aggregation call using push or some other technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group over a particular `_id`, and apply aggregation operators such as `$min` and `$sum`, there exists only one record per group(`_id`), that holds the sum and the minimum date for that group. So there is no way to obtain a different `sum` and a different `minimum` date for the same `_id`, which also logically makes no sense.

What you would want to do is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"userId":"THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID"}},
{$unwind:"$items"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "values":{$sum:"$items.value"},
         "dateTime":{$min:"$items.dateTime"}}}
])
```

But in case when you do not query for a particular `userId`, then you would have multiple groups, each group having its own `sum` and `min` date. Then it makes sense to accumulate all these results together in an array using the `$push` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$items"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "result":{$sum:"$items.value"},
         "dateTime":{$min:"$items.dateTime"}}},
{$group:{"_id":null,"result":{$push:{"value":"$result",
                                     "dateTime":"$dateTime",
                                     "id":"$_id"}}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"result":1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use following  aggregation may it works

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
                           {"$unwind":"$items"},
                           {"$match":{"userId":"THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID"}},
                          {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","sum":{"$sum":"$items.value"},
                          "minDate":{"$min":"$items.dateTime"}}}
                           )
```